# Loop through table rows with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I want to get link from each row in a table. That's how I get 3rd (for example):

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(#content-tabs-0 > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.mpt-1-td-desc > a").href)
```

I want to iterate through table rows, I use such code:

```
for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
let link = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#content-tabs-0 
> div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+i+") > td.mpt-1-td-desc > a").href);
console.log(link);
}
```

When i execute code, i get such error:

```
(node:16928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: i is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:87
(node:16928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js
process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How should it be done correctly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Good day
You can get the content of the page and then with the help of cheerio go through elements and parse them.

Comment: working simply and fast, thanks :) but I think there should be some build in feature in puppeteer to make things even simpler